# Programmatic scroll on a div with parent with overflow-x hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is exactly what it is described in the title.
I have a parent which has `overflow-x: hidden`.
I have 3 rows which has some content overflowing.

In this scenario I am not able to programmatically scroll one of the rows.
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6v1xydn/5/

But if I change the rows to have `overflow-x: auto`, programmatic scrolling works but it also shows up a horizontal scrollbar.
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6v1xydn/6/

Question: I want to understand why it is happening like that. And how can I get the scroll to work without the horizontal scrollbar showing up? (And no hiding the horizontal scrollbar using css **is not an option**)

PS: Would prefer a no plain HTML/CSS/JS answer. **No jQuery**

**Update 1**: Parent positioning doesn't seem to affect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you move

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

onto the row-class instead.

And you really don't need the overflow-x: hidden on the container as every item you put inside it so far has its width set to 100%.

Comment: Works!! Can you explain why this works? And what I have asked in the question doesn't?

Comment: I am pretty sure this works because the overflow needs to be hidden before you  are able to scroll the element. When you put the overflow-x: hidden on the container, each item inside it actually had its overflow-attribute set to visible. I think you could actually set the overflow-x to hidden on both the container and the items inside it to make sure there is now possibility for overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/cornelraiu/w6v1xydn/8/

Setting the children divs to position relative like this:

```
#container > div {position: relative;left:0}
```

and then in js:

```
document.getElementById("row1").style.left = '-50px';
```

This should work

Comment: Does work. But creating a string value `'-50px'` everytime I want to scroll programmatically seems too shabby to me

Comment: Then use Falle1234's method. That is cleaner

Comment: I don't remember you saying anything about the offsetLeft property in the original question :)